# Im having trouble making language translation VBA Cases in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, case

Im trying to make Vba cases to make an automatic language translation code for a document list filled with house items, but some lines have more than one item and i need vba to translate each one of them individually in the same cell, the solution i found was to write every possibility (in the translation the order doesnt matter) here is the lines im using:

```
Sub Traduccione()
Select Case activecell.Offset.Value
    Case "Cadeiras"
    Selection.Value = "Chairs"
Case "Cadeira"
Selection.Value = "Chair"
Case "Criado mudo", "Criado-mudo"
Selection.Value = "Night stand"
Case "Mesa"
Selection.Value = "Table"
Case "Mesas", "mesas"
Selection.Value = "Tables"
Case "Mesa de canto"
Selection.Value = "End table"
Case "Mesinha"
Selection.Value = "Small table"
Case "Cabeceira", "cabeceira"
Selection.Value = "Headboard"
Case "Cabeceiras", "cabeceiras" 
'the following lines are an example of my struggle:
Case "Mochila, documentos e roupas", "Mochila, roupas e documentos", "Documentos, mochilas e roupas", "Documentos, roupas e mochilas", "Roupas, mochilas e documentos", "Roupas, documentos e mochilas"
Selection.Value = "Bags, documents and clothes"

Case "Travesseiro, bolsas, sapatos e roupas", "Travesseiro, bolsas, roupas e sapatos", "Travesseiro, sapatos, bolsas e roupas", "Travesseiro, sapatos, roupas e bolsas", "Travesseiro, roupas, bolsas e sapatos", "Travesseiro, roupas, sapatos e bolsas", "Bolsas, travesseiro, sapatos e roupas", "Bolsas, travesseiro, roupas e sapatos", "Bolsas, sapatos, travesseiro e roupas", "Bolsas, sapatos, roupas e travesseiro", "Bolsas, roupas, travesseiro e sapatos", "Bolsas, roupas, sapatos e travesseiro", "Sapatos, travesseiro e bolsas, roupas", "Sapatos, travesseiro, roupas e bolsas", "Sapatos, bolsas, travesseiro e roupas", "Sapatos, bolsas, roupas e travesseiro", "Sapatos, roupas, travesseiro e bolsas", "Sapatos, roupas, bolsas e travesseiro", "Roupas, travesseiro, bolsas e sapatos", "Roupas, travesseiro, sapatos e bolsas", "Roupas, bolsas, travesseiro e sapatos", "Roupas, bolsas, sapatos e travesseiro", "roupas, sapatos, travesseiro e bolsas", "Roupas, sapatos, bolsas e travesseiro"
Selection.Value = "Pillow, bags, shoes and clothes"
       End Select

End Sub
```

This list goes on with more than 1000 items, this is just a sample for you briliant minds to understand.

I want to know if there is a better way to do this, because I cant find a better solution, I think there should be a better way to do it but i just cant find it, if someone had a similar problem or know how to make this job easier, could you please share? You would make my life easier.

Im a newbie here and in coding so please be patient if im doing a weird mistake :b

Thank you folks for reading.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary rather than a cascade of case statements?

Comment: And use the `Split` function against the comma-delimited lists.

Comment: How about building a table in a sheet with the list and using [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1). This way you can avoid VBA altogether and will have easier time building the list. (Just type in Excel cells).

Comment: While the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) is always part of the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property, the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property is not always the same as the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx); e.g. the Selection could be multiple cells.

Comment: Use TRIM(LCase(ActiveCell.Value)) so you don't have to worry about upper and lower case or leading or trailing spaces

Comment: Whether you store the translations as key and item in a dictionary, in a pair of arrays or even oin teh worksheet to be brought into a two-dimensioned array, I think you would be best with a [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) on the whole string using **LookAt:=xlPart**. You wouldn't need Cadeiras / Chairs since replacing Cadeira with Chair would leave the **s**. Case-sensitivity can be ignored. Some care would have to be made to ensure that they were replaced in the correct order. Show the translations as a sample data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using a dictionary object, and the string `Replace` function. This will not attempt to translate any words which are NOT in the dictionary.

```
Sub foo()

Dim translate As Object 'Scritping.Dictionary

Set translate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Define your translation terms
' here I use lower-case for everything, assuming that case-sensitivity does not matter
    translate("cadeira") = "chair"
    translate("cadeiras") = "chairs"
    translate("criado mudo") = "night stand"
    translate("criado-mudo") = "night stand"
    translate("mesa") = "table"
    translate("mesas") = "tables"

    ' etc...
    ' Add more translation items as needed

Dim spWords As String
Dim enWords As String

spWords = LCase(ActiveCell.Value)

For Each spWord In translate.Keys()
    If InStr(spWords, spWord) Then
        enWords = Replace(Replace(spWords, spWord, translate(spWord), InStr(spWords, spWord)), " e ", "and")
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = enWords

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a good feeling about this way of coding /\, i dont understand how to use object nor each, I will try to learn it, cuz when i tried to run the code it returned an error "The variant for each needs to be a variant or object"

Comment: Change to `Dim spWord as Variant`

Comment: I revised the answer with the change mentioned above.

Comment: Man!! I cant believe how amazing you are!! It is looking and translating each cell exactly as I wanted! You are amazing David!

Comment: I just need to find a solution for this kind of line: translate("criado mudo") = "night stand"

Because it is looking up first for "Criado" and then for "mudo" instead of going for both words

Comment: David, do you know what i could do to make vba write all the words translated by each in the activecell? Sorry if im asking too much

Comment: OK I see the problem of course is that you have mixed delimiters: a comma by itself is not sufficient because of the `e` (*and*) translation. But a space is not sufficient, because of compound words. Let me think of a hack solution...

Comment: See revision, I think that might help.

Comment: I made a small correction and updated the code, but still I cant figure out why the first "Replace"  returns the following error  "The argument aint optional". 

I so excited about this code David lo, do you know what is genetaring this error?

Comment: David, you are the best, im giving you the correct answer for you helped more than I was expecting. thank you very much for the attention. Sorry for asking too much even after you helped me. Wish i could reward you better than giving you the right answer, you deserve more than that.

Comment: I made some revisions, had some misplaced parentheses/etc., but I think it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining a list like this is not typically done by hard-coding the literals into the program. Rather, the data is typically stored in a more durable place, like a database and the program then accesses the database by performing a query.

Short of that, you should store your data somewhere as maintaining the Select/Case is not sustainable. You could create a Dictionary like this:

```
 Dim MyDictionary As Object
 Set MyDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

And then add each pair of data like this:

```
 MyDictionary.Add "Cadeiras", "Chairs"
```

After the Dictionary is populated, you can loop through it, looking for a match like this:

```
 For Each key In MyDictionary.Keys
      ' theInput is the data that is being looked up
      If theInput = key Then
         Selection.Value = MyDictionary.Item(key)
      End If
 Next word
```

Comment: Do you think I should build it on access? I'm tryin to learn it since yesterday, trying to see if it would be easier.

Comment: To do it correctly, it will be more work, no doubt. But, this is the correct way. You could use Access as long as you are not going to have multiple users accessing the DB simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This solution (put this on a module , even if i prefer class implementation) works in both way !

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

'Note : Specify your language. Watch out first native language should be 0
Public Enum tr_language
    english = 0
    french = 1
End Enum

Public Function dicOfTerms() As String()
'Note : Your translate Dictionary. Dim your array (carefull Option base 1)
Dim trData(2) As String

trData(1) = "dog;chien"
trData(2) = "mug;tasse"

dicOfTerms = trData
End Function

Public Function myTerm(ByVal targetString As String, Optional translatelanguage As tr_language = 1) As String
Dim tmp() As String

'Note : Warning  vbBinaryCompare is case sensitive | vbTextCompare is not case sensitive !
tmp = Filter(dicOfTerms, targetString, True, vbTextCompare)
'Note : return tarrgetString if not translation !
If UBound(tmp) < 0 Then myTerm = targetString Else myTerm = Split(tmp(0), ";")(translatelanguage)

End Function

Sub test_translate()
    Debug.Print myTerm("dog", french)
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, your code looks so advanced, I cant understand the error " The type defined by the user wasnt defined" on the following line:
Public Function myTerm(ByVal targetString As String, Optional translatelanguage As tr_language = 1) As String

Do you know what is going on?

Comment: you should put "Public Enum tr_language...." on top of your module (juste after "Option Base 1"